# pgAdmin4 won't let me drag select in the results grid

Tags: pgadmin-4

I recently upgraded to the latest pgAdmin 4 (version 6.9), and to my surprise, drag-selecting in the results grid doesn't work (it's just not selecting anything). I can move the active
cell around using the arrow keys and clicking, but drag selecting or shift-arrow selecting
just moves the active cell around without selecting the cells. I can't seem to find a setting that changes this.

Is this a bug, or is it configured in some non-obvious way? How do I change this?

Running on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is indeed a bug:

https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/7380

> Unable to select results in grid using keys CTRL or Shift - version
> 6.9
>
> Description
>
> Since i've updated my client i can't select results in grid using keys
> CTRL or Shift.